# Is there a way to use restsharp with windows 10 universal apps?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, restsharp, portable-rest

Does anyone know of a workaround to get restsharp working with windows 10 universal apps? I know there was a workaround for 8.1 and I know that the portablerest project exists however I cannot seem to get that to send post requests at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restsharp doesn't support UWP right now.

You can use `HttpClient`and `PostAsync()` method for now!